# Delete a string from an array in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I'm writing some code in Python to read from a file some text, and make a 2-dimensional array from it. But when I make the array, in the last spot of the first 2 array(of three) there is : '\n', and I want delete it.

This is the file(data.txt):

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z,
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z
```

And this is the Python code:

```
data = open("data.txt", mode="r")

arr = data.readlines()

for i in range(len(arr)):
    arr[i] = list(arr[i].split(","))

#here I tryed to detele it
for i in range(len(arr)):
    if arr[i][len(arr[i])-1] == '\\n':
       del arr[len(arr[i])-1]

data.close()
```

This is the result of the code(but there is anyway '\n'):

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '\n']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '\n']
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
```

How I could delete those?

Comment: the `\n` is a *newline* character to indicate a line break in the file you're reading. you can use the `list.pop` or `.remove` functions, or you can simply do like `arr[i] = arr[i][:-1]`.

Comment: These are `"\n"`, not `"\\n"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short solution using `str.rstrip()` and `str.splitlines()` functions:

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    items = [l.rstrip(',').split(',') for l in f.read().splitlines()]
    print(items)
```

The output:

```
[['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z'], ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rstrip` and list comprehension.

```
with open("data.txt", 'r', encoding="utf-8") as file:
    array = [line.rstrip(',\n').split(',') for line in file]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the list and only keep values that are not "\n":

```
for i in range(len(arr)):
     arr[i] = [b for b in arr[i] if b != "\n"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just strip the `\n` as you read the lines:

```
arr = []

with open('data.txt', mode="r") as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        arr.append(line.strip(',\n').split(','))

print arr
```